# Is it possible to convert from Bits to SpinalEnum?

Tags: spinalhdl

I have a SlaveFactory and I'd like to save some flags in registers as SpinalEnums. Is it possible to cast Bits to my SpinalEnum on write operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically on `AxiLite4SlaveFactory` side I have something like this:

```scala
val gen_stop_type = RegInit(StopType.stop_frame.asBits)
busCtrl.write(gen_stop_type, JumboBridgeAXIReg.GEN_STOP.id)
io.gen_stop_type_o.assignFromBits(gen_stop_type)
```

`StopType` is my `SpinalEnum`. So going line by line:

1. The key here is `.asBits`, when initialising with a default value – it is in `Bits` type, but with correct bit length according to `StopType` length when encoded in hardware.
2. A regular `SlaveFactory.write` method (which now references to `Bits` register, not `StopType` register, what caused errors before).
3. The key is `.assignFromBits`, which I found, when looking through docs. Basically every hardware type has this method (and `SpinalEnum` is a hardware type), so it's possible to "convert" `Bits` (with width previously derived from the enum) to `StopType` enum.

Comment: You should also be able to do bits.as(YourEnum()) which I find is nicer than assignFromBits, as it is an expression and not a statement

.as() will pretty much accept anything, for instance .as(UInt(2 bits)) is also fine